# Apache not loading cURL extension

Tags: php, apache, curl, windows-7

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- Apache 2.4.16 VC11 32 bits
- PHP 5.4.43 VC9 ts 32 bits

And:

- I have php installed on C:\DevTools\php and made that directory Path accessible (so curl extension has access to libeay32 and ssleay32 dll's).
- extension_dir is correctly set on php.ini. as extension_dir = "C:\DevTools\php\ext".
- extension=php_curl.dll is uncommented on php.ini.

I'm getting the following message on Apache error log:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\DevTools\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Just in case, I can add that I had previously Zend Server installed. So, I had two Apache installations, and even when I was running the one I kept (not the Zend one), I wasn't experiencing this issue.